Change font of tab bar labels?
I'm trying to implement a custom font (OpenSans) in my SwiftUI app.
Most of my views are happy to take the font and I know therefore that it's being loaded from the bundle correctly. However, there are a couple of places it's being problematic.
The first was the navigation bar, but I was able to use the appearance proxy to modify the titleTextAttributes dictionary to solve this.
The other problematic part, and the one I've not yet been able to solve, the tab bar buttons. Wherever I try to modify the font, it seemingly doesn't work - perhaps the TabView APIs internally are modifying the font back? Here's what I've tried (I'm using SwiftGen for resource accessors):

Applying the font modifier to a Label view provided by the tabItem modifier (<iOS 18)
TabView {
    Text("My tab content here...")
        .tabItem {
            Label(
                title: {
                    Text(SFAssetVerificationUI.L10n.audits)
                        .font(FontFamily.OpenSans.extraBold.swiftUIFont(fixedSize: 18))
                },
                icon: { SFAssetVerificationUI.Asset.icTabAudits.swiftUIImage }
            )
        }
}


Applying the font modifier to a Label view provided as the label argument to a Tab view (>=iOS 18).
TabView {
    Tab(
        content: {
            Text("My tab content here...")  
        },
        label: {
            Label(
                title: {
                    Text(SFAssetVerificationUI.L10n.audits)
                        .font(FontFamily.OpenSans.extraBold.swiftUIFont(fixedSize: 18))
                },
                icon: { SFAssetVerificationUI.Asset.icTabAudits.swiftUIImage }
            )
        }
    )
}


Swapping out both the above Label views for a VStack containing an Image view and a Text view.
TabView {
    Tab(
        content: {
            Text("My tab content here...")  
        },
        label: {
            VStack {
                SFAssetVerificationUI.Asset.icTabAudits.swiftUIImage
                Text(SFAssetVerificationUI.L10n.audits)
                    .font(FontFamily.OpenSans.extraBold.swiftUIFont(fixedSize: 18))
            }
        }
    )
}


Setting titleTextAttributes on the UITabBarItem appearance proxy, for both normal and selected states.
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.font: FontFamily.OpenSans.extraBold.font(size: 18)], for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.font: FontFamily.OpenSans.extraBold.font(size: 18)], for: .selected)




You might want to consider using a custom tab bar instead, then you can style it any way you like. See SwiftUi Change Tint of Unselected Item in Tab Bar for an example.
